# Basic iOS Networking Questions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to do my first App which is a basic joke app that uses tableViews and allows users to add their own jokes to the app database. My problem is in the networking department and I think I'm getting confused with all that is out there. I have a couple basic questions that I was hoping to get answers or opinions on:

1. I am really confused about the path that is taken from the app on the iphone to the database that is holding the data. Does the tableview controller call a AFNetworking object, that then sends a JSON object to a server-side script(??), that then queries a SQL database and returns the data? I am just looking for a basic path that allows the user to add their own joke to the database.
2. Is this a URL request? When I see URL request I think of a web page.
3. I have a website that is hosted on GoDaddy.com. Is this also sufficient to hold the database for the jokes on the iOS app?

I have been searching for days and have gotten no simple answer. I just want to study the correct subjects instead of wasting time. ANY help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have two forms of storage here - some form of web store (such as a server database technology like MySQL) and the local iOS CoreData (if you want to store locally, or make a new request every time thus requiring a connection). You can use web requests (perhaps using the AFNetworking library) to ensure that the local store and the online store match. A typical flow could be for example - on app launch perform a GET request to pull all jokes from the server using a service URL that returns a JSON file, then update Coredata. To upload a new joke, use a POST request which performs a similar function.
2. A 'URL request' maps to a web technology which uses some form of logic to determine how to return some data. For example, the request may arrive at a web server (such as Apache) which routes your request to a PHP controller file which then talks with the database and returns your data.
3. GoDaddy is a hosting platform that supports PHP and MySQL (amongst other technologies that will do the same trick), so yes.

In your situation, I would study the Model-View-Controller design pattern. Your app will be a great learning experience I think, you should pick up a lot of core concepts.

**EDIT to answer your question in the first comment:**

Your question:
1. Are JSON files stored on the device or the server? 2. Does JSON replace JavaScript?

Answers:

JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation, it's just a way of representing data and doesn't replace anything. It's particularly useful because most languages support parsing JSON in a way that the technology understands. It's a handy way of sending data around because it's pretty lightweight and is widely supported.

In a case like this, the JSON would probably not be stored on the server. The data would be stored in a database. Your request will be mapped to a server side technology such as PHP or Ruby which will then ask the database for the information, convert it to JSON for sending and return it to the client. (It is possible to store data on a server in a JSON file, but you would have to write your server side code to manipulate the JSON file directly, it would be hard work and way less elegant!)

The client (in this case an iOS device) will parse the JSON into an object that Objective-C can play with, like an NSDictionary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Adam. Things are clearer now. Quick follow up, 1. Are JSON files stored on the device or the server? 2. Does JSON replace JavaScript?